# Is there a simple way to clear the cache/cookies *JUST* for a specific website in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, caching, cookies

It would be extremely useful for web development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Firefox (I'm using 3.5.3):
Tools->Options->Privacy tab->Remove individual cookies
And then just type the domain/site name and you can delete those cookies:
[image: dialog box to delete individual cookies]

Answer (score 2):

I believe the [Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60) allows you to clear domain cookies. Have you checked that out?

Answer (score 0):

Only cookies, which has already been answered.  For the cache, it's not possible, but there is [a bug filed](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=524150) if you wanted to try and tackle that problem!